# How to solve an equation with x as a power and as a product

Tags: logarithms, exponential-function

Doing some exercises I have encountered an equation I could not solve. I know it has a numerical solution of about 1.835 but I am missing the algebraic methods to get to that solution analyticaly.

$$\ln({x})=\frac{1+x}{1+2x} \ \implies \ x=e^{\frac{1+x}{1+2x}}$$

I would like to know what algebraic methods I am missing and which should I learn next to solve equations like this one.

Comment: Do you have reason to believe there is a nice formula for the solution?

Comment: You can compare with similar equations, e.g. [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/204127/solve-exx-1), and the methods used.

Comment: You probably can only prove that there is a solution and exhibit a “nice” convergent sequence to this solution, but I don’t think you will get a closes form

Comment: Few root solving problems involving transcendental functions can be solved algebraically.  Those that can are typically "wired" to do so.  That is, they are carefully designed so that a solution drops out easily and then one just has to argue that other solutions do not exist.

Comment: I never said I believed there was a formula, I just want to know what should I learn to solve this type of problems

Comment: So, learn numerical methods.  Newton's method, for example, or simple binary search to start.  In this particular case, the left hand is strictly increasing while the right hand decreases to $\frac 12$.  Easy to see that the solution is unique and simple methods get you in the ball park.

Comment: In terms of some specific transformations, you might find the RHS more or less interesting by changing it into $1-\frac x{1+2x}$ or $\frac 12+\frac 1{2+4x}$.  This does not lead immediately to any interesting solutions as far as I know, but might be worth further investigation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way is by applying [Lagrange reversion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrange_reversion_theorem) and letting $x=\frac1w$:

$$\ln(x)=\frac{x+1}{2x+1}\iff ew=\sqrt[w+2]e\implies w=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{e^{-n}}{n!}\left.\frac{d^{n-1}}{dw^{n-1}}e^\frac nw\right|_2$$

If we wanted to expand $\frac1x$ as a series only, it would [diverge](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=lim%5B1%2Fy%2Bsum%5Be%5E-n%2Fn%21+D%5BD%5B1%2Fy%5D+exp%28n%2F%28y%2B2%29%29%2C%7By%2Cn-1%7D%5D%2C%7Bn%2C1%2C12%7D%5D%2Cy-%3E0.01%5D). Maclaurin series uses [factorial power $n^{(m)}$](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FactorialPower.html).

$$\frac{d^{n-1}}{dw^{n-1}}e^\frac nw =\sum_{m=0}^\infty\frac{n^m (-m)^{(n-1)}}{y^{m+n-1}m!}$$

which is just a [confluent hypergeometric $\,_1\text F_1(a;b;x)$](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=Hypergeometric1F1) or [Laguerre $\operatorname L_n^r(x)$](https://functions.wolfram.com/HypergeometricFunctions/Hypergeometric1F1/03/01/03/0006/) function. Expanding [$\operatorname L_n^1(x)$’s integral representation](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=N%5B%7BLaguerreL%289-1%2C1%2Ceulergamma%29%2CNintegrate%5B%28e%5E%28i+t+-+e%5E%28i+t%29+eulergamma%29+%281+%2B+e%5E%28-i+t%29%29%5E9%29%2F%282+%CF%80%29%2C%7Bt%2C0%2C2%CF%80%7D%5D%7D%5D) gives us an integral solution:

$$\bbox[4px,border:4px #90EE90 double]{x=\frac1{\frac1e-\sum_\limits{n=1}^\infty(-2e)^{-n}\,_1\text F_1\left(n;2;\frac n2\right)}=\frac1{\frac1{\sqrt e}-\frac1{4\pi}\int_0^{2\pi} e^{\frac{ e^{it}}2+it-\frac12}\ln\left(\frac12(e^{it}+1)e^{\frac{e^{it}}2-it-\frac12}+1\right)dt}}$$

Typing in `RealDigits[1/(1/E-NSum[(-2E)^(-n) Hypergeometric1F1[n,2,n/2],{n,1,7000}])]` into Mathematica matches the many first true digits:

[image]

while the, rounded, integral is [shown here](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=1%2F%281%2F%E2%88%9Ae-Nintegrate%5B%28e%5E%281%2F2+%28-1+%2B+e%5E%28i+t%29+%2B+2+i+t%29%29+log%281+%2B+1%2F2+e%5E%281%2F2+%28-1+%2B+e%5E%28i+t%29+-+2+i+t%29%29+%281+%2B+e%5E%28i+t%29%29%29%29%2F%284+%CF%80%29%2C%7Bt%2C0%2C2%CF%80%7D%5D%29)

Another way uses the [Ramanujan master theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ramanujan%27s_master_theorem), which would give the same series expansion or [Mellin inversion](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mellin_inversion_theorem) which would possibly give another integral representation with a similar integrand.

Comment: Thanks very much for your answer and taking the time to elaborate so much, it was very helpful. I will definitely learn about all that you mentioned

Comment: @mathsandscience If more details are wanted, they can be edited in

Comment: its ok, im looking at all the theorems you mentioned

Comment: To all: The series expansion, using either $_1F_1$ or $L_n^r(x)$, is about the same one gotten from the “generalized Lambert function” paper in other answers.

Answer (score 2):

By inspection, you know that the zero of function
$$f(x)=\log(x)-\frac{x+1}{2x+1}$$ is rather close to $x=2$.

By Taylor around this point
$$f(x)= \left(\log (2)-\frac{3}{5}\right)+\sum_{n=1}^\infty (-1)^n \frac{4^n\, n+2\ 5^{n+1} }{10^{n+1}\,n}\, (x-2)^n$$
Truncating to some order $(p+1)$ and using [power series reversion](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/SeriesReversion.html)
$$x=2+\sum_{n=1}^p a_n \,t^n+O(t^{p+1}) \qquad \text{where} \qquad t=f(x)-\left(\log (2)-\frac{3}{5}\right)$$ the first coefficient being
$$\left\{\frac{50}{27},\frac{5875}{6561},\frac{479375}{1594323},\frac
   {4371875}{57395628},\frac{5668796875}{376572715308},\frac{450991484375}{183014339639688}\right\}$$

Since we want $f(x)=0$, for this level of expansion, converted to decimals,
$$x_{(6)}=\color{red}{1.8350370674}51$$

Answer (score 2):

$$\log(x)=\frac{x+1}{2x+1}$$
$$\frac{x+1}{2x+1}=t \implies x=\frac{1-t}{2t-1}\implies \log \left(\frac{1-t}{2 t-1}\right)=t$$ Exponentiate and reverse
$$e^{-t}=\frac{2 t-1}{1-t}$$ The only explicit solution is given in terms  of the [generalized Lambert function](https://arxiv.org/abs/1408.3999) (have a look at equation $(4)$ in the linked paper).

Comment: Thanks very much. I thought it could be solved with something involving Lambert W function but did not know how.